# Open http://localhost in linux cmd

Tags: linux

I've searched internet and I can't find a solution. How to open this localization in linux from cmd http://localhost/test/main? How could I open http://google.com ?

Comment: Uhm...A browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the commands `sensible-browser` followed by the URL you want to open.

ex: `sensible-browser http://google.com`

Hope that helps.